# V8 Garbage Collection is very slow

Tags: c++, multithreading, embed, v8

I have developed a realtime 3D Engine and now I want to switch to V8 JavaScript engine. The implementation was very easy an everything was ok except I have a problem with the Garbage Collection, it causes an important performace leak. Due to technical reason I need agressive Garbage Collection so I do to collect garbage:

v8::V8::LowMemoryNotification ();

which does what I want, but very slow. I also have already tried:

V8::IdleNotification ();

but then the Garbage Collection cause long breaks when it realy performs.

What is the best way to implement the V8 Garbage Collection in a real time 3D application, how do I have to think? What about multithreading?

It seems important to say that the 3d scenes can have dozends of script, each script is running in a separate Isolate.

Answer (score 0):

Having each script running in a separate `Isolat`e is probably not what you want. You should consider instead sharing a single `Isolate` and just segregating them with separate `Context`s instead.

You should also be running your JavaScript on its own dedicated thread, using appropriate native IPC mechanisms to communicate with your user thread.  Then, the appropriate means of performing garbage collection is using `v8::IdleNotification()` on a regular basis (and only calling `v8::LowMemoryNotification()` when you're legitimately running out of memory), and simply give it a limit for how long it can spend on it.  If you need additional threads for your game logic, you can have an `Isolate` per thread, and split up your `Context`s that way (although you will be unable to migrate your scripts between threads if you do that).

There's also a newer API for running "micro-tasks" which may be appropriate for what you want, although as of February 2015 it appears to still be experimental.

And, of course, make sure that your scripts are generating as little garbage as possible in the first place. Avoid creating new objects on a per-frame basis, including functions and local variables that get enclosed by them.  Also, try pre-allocating all of your state in a single property bag up-front.  That will do a lot to reduce the amount of garbage that needs to be collected in the first place.